# JavaScript функция запускается один раз

Tags: javascript

Привет, есть пагинация, на сайте, например,
при нажатии на одну из кнопок( их 10, допустим,) которые переключаются по страницам я подгружаю данные из сервера
как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии второй раз на одну и ту же кнопку данные не подгружались

---

чего-то не хватает) я просто добавляю атрибут disabled='true' по кликнутой кнопке, какое-то действие навесить должен что ли)

Answer (score 1):

добавляй после нажатия на кнопку ей атрибут disabled="true" и убирай все disabled у остальных кнопок

Comment: добавил атрибут и удаляю у других, что дальше?)

Comment: и все равно кликается два раза?

Comment: чего-то не хватает) я просто добавляю атрибут disabled='true' по кликнутой кнопке, какое-то действие навесить должен что ли)

Comment: попробуйте добавить просто атрибут disabled, например, <input id="id" name="name" value="value" disabled/>, а если кнопка обернута еще и в тег A, то и у него добавьте тег disabled

Comment: просто пагинация сделана не кнопкой а спаном)

Comment: можно попробовать навесить на span вот такую штуку <span onclick="JavaScript: return false;">Кнопка</span>

Comment: не мог бы помочь?) если мы спишемся где-нибудь в другом месте